# Delete Vs Clear Contents VB.net

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code in VB.net to delete certain Excel Sheets named as : T10, T12 , T16 and so on , so I wrote this code to delete them as follows:

```
    Sub DeleteTSheets_Restart()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim cnt As Integer
        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
        cnt = 0
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            If InStr(1, ws.Name, "T") And Len(ws.Name) = 3 Then
                ws.Delete()
            End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next ws
        xl.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Close(SaveChanges:=vbTrue)
    End Sub
```

But it does not delete them But if I use the same code and change only the line:

```
    ws.Delete with ws.Cells.ClearContents()
```

The Code Works and empty all the sheet, So why the delete is not working??

Thanks, regards

Moheb Labib

Comment: ws.Delete modifies the wb.Sheets collection, so the sheet after the one you delete gets skipped.  Work around this by iterating backwards with a For-loop

Comment: @ Hans Passant , Thanks your reply, However, can you give me a hint how ? by using `For i = 1 to wb.sheets.count` or what??

Comment: Backwards, so For i = wb.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1

Comment: @ Hans Passant , I edited the code above but it still does not work, can you revise it? Thanks

Comment: You didn't get rid of the For-Each loop.  **Replace** it with the For-loop.  You need Set ws = wb.Sheets(i) to refer to the sheet.

Comment: Don't you want to call DisableAlerts before deleting sheets?  If you make the Excel application `Visible` that might give you some more information

Comment: @ Hans Passant, I edited the code but I receive Error Invalid index when I use ws = wb.Sheets(i), So what do you suggest?

Comment: @ Hans Passant, I found the solution Thanks, I edited the Correct Code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Sub DeleteTSheets_Restart()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim cnt As Integer
        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
        cnt = 0
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            If InStr(1, ws.Name, "T") And Len(ws.Name) = 3 Then
                ws.Delete()
            End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next ws
        xl.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Close(SaveChanges:=vbTrue)
    End Sub
```